# xcode build error with undefined symbols using aruco opencv module in Xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, opencv, aruco

I've built `opencv2.framework` using OpenCV 3.4 and opencv_contrib in order to use the aruco library. I'm importing this framework into Xcode and I am able to import and use standard OpenCV modules with no compile errors.

I can `#import <aruco/aruco.h>` with no compile errors. However, as soon as I try to use any classes from aruco I get a compile error. In this case:

> Undefined symbols for aruco::MarkerDetector::~MarkerDetector()

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/core.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#import <aruco/aruco.h>

-(void)doSomething() {
    //anything in cv:: lib is fine, no compile errors
    cv::Mat mat(3,3,CV_32); 

    //but as soon as I try to use aruco I get compile error
    aruco::MarkerDetector detector;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. If I include, vs import aruco -  `#include "opencv/aruco.hpp"` I can then use aruco `cv::aruco::detectMarkers(....)`.

For some reason when I import aruco, the code completion doesn't seem to accurately reflect the API and that was causing additional confusion.